# How we can create new ticket automatically in Jira dashboard from Jenkins on job failure?

Tags: jenkins, jira

I have searched in google but did not find any relevant ans to automatically create issue from Jenkins to Jira if any job status is failed.

I found, we can configure Jira for Junit testing. Eg. If any testcase fail Jenkins will raise request to Jira. But I want the same process on build fail.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [JIRA Pipeline Steps](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jira-steps) plugin offers [numerous steps](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/jira-steps/) that allow you to interact with JIRA from a [Jenkins Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/).

I assume that the [`jiraNewIssue`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/jira-steps/#jiranewissue-jira-steps-create-new-issue) step is what you are searching for. Use this in a post failure step of your pipeline and it will create the issue for you.

Something like (untested):

```
pipeline {
  stages {
  ...
  }
  post {
    failure {
      jiraNewIssue(...)
    }
  }
}
```